# Validation activerecord

Tags: php, validation, activerecord, orm

Please, explane me this code.
Specifically, the elements in the arrays: name, blah and bleh. I check the uniqueness of username and email

```
class User extends ActiveRecord\Model
{
  static $validates_uniqueness_of = array(
    array('name'),
    array(array('blah','bleh'), 'message' => 'blah and bleh!')
  );
}

User::create(array('name' => 'Tito'));
$user = User::create(array('name' => 'Tito'));
$user->is_valid();
```

Comment: could you be more specific about what exactly you are not understanding?

Comment: Sorry. How do I check for uniqueness of values for the fields username and email in the users table

Comment: @jahller, it is here http://www.phpactiverecord.org/projects/main/wiki/Validations#validates_uniqueness_of